# Reformatting a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I need to reformat a CSV file that is being exported from a DB to fit the criteria for another DB.  I ordered the CSV based on the "recipient" field (email address).  What I need this to do is, if an email address repeats it should tag the last row "Concat" to the previous line with "|" as a separator. It needs to end up looking like this:

```
recipient,lastSent,aftersunset,notes,fk_rty_id,confirmed,rty_id,rty_type,EnglishDate,,Concat
"   bheller@email.org",1/21/17 5:00,1,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,1/9/1991,01/09/1991,JOEL E. WEINGARTEN-01/09/1991
"   123456@email.com",6/29/16 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,6/11/2015,06/11/2015,ANN SCHONBERG-06/11/2015|ALEXANDER SCHONBERG-12/26/2009
1234benn@email.net,3/24/17 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,3/20/1985,03/20/1985,LEE I HOWARD-03/20/1985|IDA GALES-02/27/1990
```

Here is my CSV

```
recipient,lastSent,aftersunset,notes,fk_rty_id,confirmed,rty_id,rty_type,EnglishDate,,Concat
"   bheller@email.org",1/21/17 5:00,1,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,1/9/1991,01/09/1991,JOEL E. WEINGARTEN-01/09/1991
"   123456@email.com",6/29/16 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,6/11/2015,06/11/2015,ANN SCHONBERG-06/11/2015
"   123456@email.com",1/6/17 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,12/26/2009,12/26/2009,ALEXANDER SCHONBERG-12/26/2009
1234benn@email.net,3/24/17 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,3/20/1985,03/20/1985,LEE I HOWARD-03/20/1985
1234benn@email.net,2/27/17 5:00,0,,1,1,1,Yahrzeit,2/27/1990,02/27/1990,IDA GALES-02/27/1990
```

Here is the PHP code that I have so far:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("yz-email.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {

        $data = fgetcsv($file); 
        $num = count($data);

        $concat = $data[22];

        if ($concat != $newConcat ) { 

                /*for ( $c=0; $c<$num;$c++) {

                    print $data[$c].",";

                } */


            $newConcat = $concat;

        } else {

            array_push($data, $newConcat);
        }


            print "<pre>";
            print_r($data);
            print "</pre>";


        }



fclose($file);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to load the whole set of data into an array, and the write into a resulting CSV. This approach can only cause troubles if the amount of data is huge and won't fit into PHP's allowed memory. Here is a sample script that does the job. It assumes the first row is a header.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('yz-email.csv','r');
$hdr = false;
$skip_header = true;
$data = [];
$contact_index = null; // Will take the last column index, if not set

if ($fp) {
  while(!feof($fp)) {
    $row = fgetcsv($fp);

    // Skip empty lines
    if ((count($row) === 1) && is_null($row[0])) continue;

    // Skip header
    if (!$hdr) {
      $hdr = true;
      if (!isset($contact_index)) $contact_index = count($row)-1;
      if ($skip_header) continue;
    }

    $email = strtolower(trim($row[0]));
    if (isset($data[$email])) $data[$email][$contact_index].='|'.trim($row[$contact_index]);
    else $data[$email] = array_map('trim',$row);
  }
  fclose($fp);
}

$fp = fopen('result.csv','w');
if ($fp) {
  foreach($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp,$row);
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started over, please forgive me for not utilizing your exact code and building from there.  I added inline documentation, so it should be easy to follow.

```
<?php
  $fname    = "emails.csv";                               //name of input file
  $strOut = "";                                           //output string
  $fileContents = file_get_contents($fname);              //read contents of file
  $arrData = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $fileContents));;        //convert string into an array
  $i=0;                                                   //counter
  $lastEmail = "";

  foreach($arrData as $row) {                              //loop over the array
    if(count($row) > 1) {                                 //for some reason, I was getting an extra empty array element, so I make sure it's a valid row here
      if(compareEmails($row[0],$lastEmail)) {             //if different email, just append array
        $strOut = $strOut . "|" .$row[10];
      } else {
        $strOut .= "\r\n";                              //ad the carriage return to the previous row, because we know it's a new email
        $strOut = appendToString($row,$strOut);         //append to string
      }
      $i++;
    }
    $lastEmail = $row[0];
  }

  function appendToString($arrIn,$strOut) {               //append the content onto the string
    $strOut .= $arrIn[0] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[1] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[2] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[3] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[4] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[5] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[6] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[7] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[8] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[9] . ",";
    $strOut .= $arrIn[10];
    return $strOut;
  }
  function compareEmails($curEmail,$lastEmail) {
    $curEmail = trim(str_replace('"', "", $curEmail));      //remove the quotes
    $lastEmail = trim(str_replace('"', "", $lastEmail));    //remove the quotes
    if($curEmail == $lastEmail) {                           //compare them
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
 ?>
<pre>
  <?php echo $strOut; ?>
</pre>
```